# How to assign values within an object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to assign values within an object in react?

like this!

```
import { initialState } from '../store/initialState';

const Func = state => {
  initialState = {
    ...state,
  }; //error!
}
```

Comment: `initialState ` when it is defined would be `const`. Also, you are modifying an imported modules, which is a BAD practice. Try `(state) => ({ ...initialState, ...state })`

Answer (score 0):

No you cant reassign imported variable because `import { initialState } ....` is equal with `const initialState  = ...`

You can export a method for assigning initialState  :

```
let initialState  = ....

let setInitialState = (state) => {
    initialState  = {
       ...state
    }
}

export { initialState  , setInitialState };
```

Then:

```
import{ initialState  , setInitialState } from ...;

const Func = state => {
  setInitialState(state)
}
```